# How to fire JS function from area href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a image with a link map like this (generated in PHP):

```
        <map name="map_bc-03" id="map_bc-03">
          <area shape="circle" coords="166,28,12" href="#" onClick="changeCount('plus','bc-03');">
          <area shape="circle" coords="166,82,11" href="#" onClick="changeCount('minus','bc-03');"> 
        </map>
```

I am trying to fire a JS function called `changeCount(type,product)`.

JS function purpose is to take the current value of a HTML element (`<span>`) and add 1 to it (x+1). JS  function looks like:

```
function changeCount(type,product)
{
    if ( type == "plus" )
    {
         $("#count_" + product).val() = $("count_" + product).val() + 1;
    }
}
```

Problem is that 1/ the JS function is not fired with error message "ReferenceError: changeCount is not defined", which I do not understand why as clearly the function is defined....

Problem number 2/ the JS function itself causes a "ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation" error (even though not fired)....

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Whats with the double +

Comment: Trying to use `++` instead of `+` for concatenation is what is causing that second error.

Comment: I updated the code, the function is fired now... Still get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on the line `$("#count_" + product).val() = $("count_" + product).val() + 1;`

Comment: did you include jquery in your code? otherwise what is $?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon actually I didn't.... can't believe that myself, just forgot to include the library..... corrected.... still throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` on `$("#count_" + product).text() = $("count_" + product).text() + 1;`

Comment: Try with: `$("#count_" + product).text($("#count_" + product).text() + 1);`

Comment: I am right now on:
`currentCount = parseInt($("#count_" + product).text());
$("count_" + product).val(currentCount+1);`
works fine, but the <span> element is not updated.....

Comment: `.val()` is for form elements. If you want to change other elements text/contents, you need `html(new value)` or `text(new value)`. So `$("count_" + product).text(currentCount+1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` is for form elements. For `<span>` you need `html()` or `text()`. try this

```
function changeCount(type,product){
    if ( type == "plus" ){
      $("#count_" + product).text(function(index, val){
        return parseInt(val)+1;
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `val(value);` instead of using `val() = value;`.

Important thing is,

if your target selector is an input or any form element then use `.val()`.
Otherwise, if it is any of `div`, `span` or any other non-form element then use `.text()` instead of `.val()`. Because, non-form elements don't have any values.

According to your question, you are targetting a `<span>`. So, I think you have to use `.text()`.

```
function changeCount(type,product)
{
  if ( type == "plus" )
    {
      $('#count_'+ product).text(Number($('#count_' + product).text()) + 1);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$("#count_" + product).val() = parseInt($("#count_" + product).val()) + 1;
```

"#" is missing while getting value and parseInt should be used.